# texpad with Arabic

Tags: arabic, texpad

I am using the latest version `texpad`. It was working fine with Arabic text. But recently, I got the following message `no log - defaulting to texput.log:
This is TexpadTeX (based on TeX Version 3.14159265 with e-TeX extensions) running in extended mode (preloaded format=latex 2018.10.31)  24 OCT 2019 21:00`

i have the following `LaTeX` code and it shows the above:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE,LFE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}

\title{Package Test: arabi for Arabic Text}

\begin{document}

\Huge
النص العربي 

\end{document}
```

w